# Load Bootstrap with a Content Script?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-chrome-extension

What's the correct way to incorporate React Bootstrap into my content scripts?

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './content/App'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

// Targeted UI component
const viewport = document.getElementById('viewport')

const app = document.createElement('div')
app.id = 'root'

// Can use appendChild instead of prepend
if (viewport) viewport.prepend(app)

ReactDOM.render(<Button bsStyle='primary'>Memes</Button>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The above does not have functionality or styling, there's no place to put the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

EDIT: iFrame approach

```js
var f = document.createElement('iframe')
f.src = chrome.extension.getURL('src/js/content/App.js')

console.log("TEST: " + f.src)

const viewport = document.getElementById('body')
viewport.prepend(f)
```

```js
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "src/js/content/App.js"
  ], ...
```

Returns little grey window with an error 'It may have been moved or deleted'

Comment: DOM elements created by a content script are not isolated from the page, they're part of the page so your UI will break unpredictably even if you make it work on one page. Usually an iframe is loaded, and the iframe code runs in full extension context with access to all API available for a normal extension page. See web_accessible_resources documentation and examples for this popular approach. BTW you should load all files from an extension directory, not from a CDN.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll add an edit for the iframe approach I tried, it simply causes chrome to report that 'it may have been moved or deleted'

Comment: @wOxxOm added it

Comment: iframe src attribute should point to an html page, not to a js script.